# Xcode error message "The remote repository rejected commits" when pushing to Github

Tags: xcode, git, github

I have a branch named **develop** that I pulled on, added some code, committed, pulled again, and am now trying to push but I get the following error message in Xcode:

> **The remote repository rejected commits.** 
>  Make sure you have permission
>   to push to the remote repository and try again.

I switched to a different branch named **feature** and was able to pull and push on it fine.

I went to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Repositories then clicked on the repository I'm working on and verified my credentials and even re-entered them. But I still have the same problem (the feature branch works but the develop one throws up that message).

Why does the push work on one branch but not the other?

Answer (score 10):

I got this error today and it wasn't until I tried to commit via another method did I actually find the reason. I had a file that was 230Mb and GitHub doesn't allow files that big (or at least for the account I have). So Xcode just wasn't being very helpful with its error message

Comment: the maximum file size is 100 MB if anyone was curious

Comment: This is the same case for me as well. Zoom simulator SDK was more than 100 MB. I excluded it from Git.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub repositories can be configured with [branch protection](https://help.github.com/articles/about-branch-restrictions/). You probably have permission only to push/pull the `feature` branch and only to pull (but not push) the `develop` branch.

Comment: This would then presumably be a question for your collaborators / masters, not SO.

Comment: By the way, I can see why they might have done this; they want you to merge onto feature before pushing, which is quite sensible in its way.

Comment: Heh, actually I am the Github Admin for our company but I am not a Github guru by any means. It does not look like I use branch protection as there are no branches listed in the protected branches section of Github. And the typical workflow we use now is to do what you said and merge develop onto feature and make sure everything works there first, then merge feature back into develop once we know everything merged fine so we don't accidentally blow up develop.

Comment: Well, obviously I don't know how you've got branch protection set up. In my own github repos, I've pushed onto non-master branches, so I know it can be done. But I have no collaborators and don't have to follow any rules. :)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I branched off of our main branch and named my branch incorrectly, so I branched off that misspelled branch to fix the name and then deleted it which killed the upstream branch for Git.

The solution was to set the upstream via command line:

```
git push --set-upstream origin theUpstreamBranchYouWantToSet
```